# Object.toString() then, encode to UTF-8

Tags: java, object, utf-8

I am trying to implement a method that converts an object into an string, an then encodes this string to UTF-8 into a .txt. So far I am able to make it work, but the what is written into the output file does not seem ok... What am I missing?

EDIT: code edited, now I get this from the file;

Arsenal                            W 10   L 02   D 03     GF 45     GA 05Chelsea                          W 08   L 02   D 05     GF 17     GA 03Aston Villa                      W 05   L 05   D 05     GF 05     GA 09Hull City                        W 06   L 04   D 05     GF 30     GA 15Inverness Caledonian Thistle     W 11   L 02   D 07     GF 50     GA 20

```
static void writeToDisk() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

        Writer  out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename_2), "UTF-8"));        

        for(FootballClubNL club : deserializeFromDisk()){

            String clubString = club.toString();

            out.append(clubString).append("\r\n");
            out.flush();    
        }
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Where do you think you're using UTF-8? Why are you using `println` rather than `write(byte[])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not specifying the encoding anywhere:

```
byte[] b = clubString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And there are other issues with your code. A simpler version of your method would be:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
for(FootballClubNL club : deserializeFromDisk()){
    lines.add(club.toString());
}
Files.write(Paths.get(filename_2), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I suspect this will truncate the file on each iteration.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ooops I missed the fact that there was more than one string - thanks.

Comment: plus one, nice use of Files.write()

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have confused writeing text with writing binary.  You have a mix of operations.  I suggest you pick one or the other or you are bound to get confused.

The problem you have is that the `byte[]` doesn't have a very useful `toString()` and even `Arrays.toString` wouldn't do what you want there.

I suspect you don't need UTF-8 encoding unless your toString() is pretty unusual.

### Writing as text

```
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filename_2)) {
    for(FootballClubNL club : deserializeFromDisk())
        pw.println(club);
}
```

### Writing as binary

```
try(OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename_2)) {
    for(FootballClubNL club : deserializeFromDisk())
        out.write(club.toString().getBytes());
}
```